# Customize Developer Console themes

Tags: css, developer-console

There is a feature to change text coloring scheme (in `Help > Preferences`).

Unfortunately, on my work monitor, it would render variable names too dark, therefore nearly invisible. Also, highlighting Visualforce tags has the color somewhat similar to tags themselves, which reduces visibility.

It looks like the same pain point exists on all dark themes.

Answer (score 3):

I've used Stylebot Chrome extension to override default CSS. There may have been a method in earlier Chrome versions to use user supplied stylesheets, but apparently it is now gone.

Import the following style into Stylebot:

```
.CodeMirror-matchingbracket {
    background-color: #80E85C;
}
.CodeMirror-matchingtag {
    background: rgba(255,00,0,.3);
}
.VARIABLE_DECLARATION {
    color: #9B9BDA;
}
.VARIABLE_REFERENCE {
    color: #9B9BDA;
}
```

Also set the matching URL to `*.salesforce.com/_ui/common/apex/debug/ApexCSIPage`

Note that this style will not work well if you are using white background themes.

It also makes selected matching open braces to highlight in brighter color.

Comment: Works pretty nice with themes for Chrome developer tools, a.i. [this](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/brogrammer-dev-tools-them/alolpfkmcjdkieibielpffiehpobafae?utm_source=chrome-app-launcher-info-dialog)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Salesforce Force.com Developer Console Dark theme](https://userstyles.org/styles/138411/salesforce-force-com-developer-console-dark-theme) on Chrome if you have the [Stylish extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylish-custom-themes-for/fjnbnpbmkenffdnngjfgmeleoegfcffe?hl=en) installed.

Disclaimer: I'm the author of that theme.

Comment: Not bad, but still missing key piece - the contrast between object variable and background is too low, look at the example `controller`: http://imgur.com/a/DWPlI The first one is using my stylesheet available for Stylebot at here https://github.com/sjurgis/salesforce-developer-console-css-fix/

Comment: I just fixed this in an updated version, thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not the answer you are looking for but: Stop using the developer console and move to visual studio code, SO MUCH BETTER! (and it works 100% without SalesforceDX, just deploy and retrieve).

Comment: I've moved to IntelliJ/IC2 long time ago. Would love a definitive comparison with VSCode. AFAIK VSCode has better lwc support, but IC2 leads aura, apex and vf.